# Does anyone know why my maps only show grid

Tags: java, xml, android

I've doubled checked my API key is right and that is right I doubled checked that it was correct.  Here is my source and XML could anyone check to see what is wrong.  Also I make sure I have internet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name=".CadetCommand"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="RedLight"></activity>
    <activity android:name="PTCalculator"></activity>
    <activity android:name="LandNav"></activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
```

```
package edu.elon.cs.mobile;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LandNav extends MapActivity{

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.landnav);
 }

 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  return false;
 }

}
```

Comment: I know you said you double checked but...  are you exporting with a particular key, or using a debug keystore?  And are you using the correct API key for whichever process you're using?  Because otherwise your code looks fine.

Comment: Also can you show the layout xml where you actually set the api key for the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

should be

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Note the lack of an 's' on android.permission